# Sharing an Apple ID on different iPads, but having different Contacts

Tags: ipad, contacts, sharing

My daughter has my old iPad, and we share the same Apple ID, for convenience with purchasing. However at present we also have a shared Contacts list on the two iPads. It would be better to have separate Contact lists, to go with our separate email accounts.  Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: In Settings.app/iCloud, you can choose to not synchronize Contacts, and others sings (like Keychain, Safari, E-Mails, and others stuffs you don't want to share).

Comment: The biggest considerations to make are: a) Find My iPhone will only work with the PRIMARY iCloud account on the iOS device, b) ditto for iCloud documents. Other than that, you can pretty much use a different Apple ID for Contacts, Messages, Calendars, FaceTime, and so forth.

Answer (score 6):

Perfectly possible, you essentially both need a free iCloud account, that you log into for the purposes or mail/calendars/notes/contacts etc etc.

You each log into iCloud from within `Settings > iCloud` with your unique ID, and turn on any appropriate option within that page once you are signed in.

Then, for the App Store, go to `Settings > iTunes and App Store` and log in again, only this time simply both use the the same ID that is associated with all your past purchases.

You can log into different ID's for different services like Facetime/Messages/App Store/Mail at the same time, it really doesn't mind.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers are correct. However, I would like to add some notes.

First of all you could also use Gmail contacts for example instead of iCloud contacts. Depending on what email you and your daughter use (iCloud/Gmail/something else) this can be even more convenient. For example, I use gmail and have all my contact stored in Gmail. This way, I have direct access to my contacts in the (rare) case that I use gmail from within my web browser. You can simply enable gmail contacts sync in Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars and then enable it at the relevant account.

Secondly, you should not forget to set the default address book accordingly. New contacts are automatically saved to that address book (in case you have multiple address books). This can be set at Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> (scroll down to header "contacts") Default Account (here you should also set default calendar and e-mail accounts btw).

In all cases, there will be one issue: you need to move (a part of) the contacts to another account. To my knowledge, you cannot easily move/copy contacts to another account in iOS ("Groups" in the upper left corner in the Contacts app in iOS). In Contacts on OSX you can drag and drop them. Also, some googling will probably give you enough sites explaining how to move contacts from icloud to icloud or icloud to gmail. It might be a good idea to make a backup (e.g. with the contacts app in osx) of your contacts as moving contacts could give some issues in some cases.

All in all it is a small investment to make in my opinion: I have moved all my contacts to gmail over 5 years ago and have used it without issues ever since. And I could easily switch to android, windows, windows phone, etc. as they all support syncing with gmail contacts.

Comment: Absolutely, there is no absolute *requirement* to use iCloud, I tend to recommend it in situations like these because the whole process of getting a new ID, configuring and using it is done *on device* on a single login, without requiring access to 3rd party websites, services etc.

Answer (score 2):

Only enter the Apple ID for purchasing into the Store section of the settings app.

You then each use separate AppleID for iCloud and / or Mail, Contacts, Calendars. One could use the same AppleID as for store, but at least one should be different and both could be different AppleID.

We have details here, here and here:

- [How to use different contacts on different iPhones with the same Apple ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/)
- [Is it a bad idea to have a shared Apple ID for purchases that also is used for iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50674/)
- [How does a family with multiple idevices and multiple laptops share music and digital movie copies?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32351/)
- [Do I need to set up individual Apple IDs for all my kids' iPads?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75429/)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here lay out good options for separating contacts and iCloud sync from purchasing, either by using two Apple IDs, or by using Google sync for your contacts... however... I strongly recommend that you and your daughter use two separate accounts for everything. I understand the desire to save money, but it can lead to pretty messy complications down the road, especially if that Apple ID is tied to the email address of an ISP (@comcast.net e.g.), and it ever has to change.

But yes, it is possible.

Comment: Well if ever my email address has to change that would mean google had turned up its toes, and that would mean an awful lot of hassles generally. Getting these kind of things sorted out would be a pretty minor part of that.

Comment: Well if ever my email address has to change that would mean google had turned up its toes, and that would mean an awful lot of hassles generally. Getting these kind of things sorted out would be a pretty minor part of that. With the icloud option I'm not clear how that would operate so far as backing up on icloud are concerned. At present I've turned off the icloud back up on both iPads while I sort out stuff like that. Does each icloud account get some storage space of its own? Would I keep my present icloud account with it's storage space (which I've enlarged?)

Comment: Each iCloud account gets 5GB of storage space by default. If you've paid for additional storage on one account, it won't grant any space to any additional iCloud accounts you set up, but yes, you could keep the existing account you have.