# Deleting Contacts

Tags: ios, contacts

I recently added an iPhone for my daughter to my account.  My phone and the new phone synced taking all my contacts to her phone.  When I deleted two numbers from her contact list, they also deleted from my phone and iPads.  Hoe can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Does your device and the other device use the same iCloud account to sync contacts? Look in the settings app to determine if they perhaps share a cloud syncing account. We can’t guess if your account is iCloud, cellular, App Store ( well we can guess, but it would be better to clarify what her contact list is, what your setup is, etc...) even if you share an account, [managing contacts separately  can be achieved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113385).

Answer (score 1):

Turn off iCloud contacts in iCloud settings on her iPhone. This will stop syncing between your and her devices.

Comment: This is an astute guess. Flag or @ me if the question gets edited and we need to reopen for more answers. This is likely it, but we may have guessed incorrectly.

Comment: @bmike That's not what flags are for